# Playwright Codegen in webview

Tags: playwright, codegen

I want to know how can we use codegen in webview2.
I can see codegen for normal web. I was not able to find solution for webview2. Please suggest solution for the same.

This works only for web
npx playwright codegen demo.playwright.dev/todomvc